# .htaccess file clean URL multiplies after each page navigation?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to create a clean URL from my PHP pages.

However, the issue that I have now is that after each page navigation, the clean URL multiplies.

for example:

my first clean URL looks like this:

```
/story/story-title-1/
```

and then from this page I navigate to another page but it will make my clean URL looks like this:

```
/story/story/story-title-2/
```

so basically, after each page navigation, the clean URL 'story' will multiply.

This is what I have in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^story/([^/]*)$ /story.php?clean=$1 [L]
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem of using relative URLs on your page not a rewrite problem.

To fix this, you can just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Otherwise** You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from root URL, not from the current page's URL.